# How to reduce any number not equal to 0 to 1 and any number equal to 0 kept at 0 in Python?

Tags: python

In Python, I want to make it so that any number greater than 0 will be reduced to 1, any number less than 0 will be brought to -1, and if the number is equal to 0, it will stay at 0. How can I do this without any if-statements? I tried dividing the number by itself, and this will return 1 for positive numbers and -1 for negative numbers, but obviously an error  for 0. Is there another solution? I am just looking for a simple, concise built-in or importable function to use.

Also, one more question: How can I do it that any number not equal to 0 is changed to 1, and any number equal to 0 remains 0 without if statements?

EDIT (to fix question as I am under question ban):

Here is the code I had originally tried for the first problem:

```
num = input("Enter num here")
num = num / abs(num)
```

However, this returns an error for 0, as it involves division by zero.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Ok I will add code for the first question, but I haven't attempted the second one yet because I don't quite know how to.

Comment: For your second question look at the built-in cmp

Comment: Are you allowed to use packages like scipy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first behaviour you list is mathematically called the signum operation. If you are allowed to use numpy, i'd simply do:

```
import numpy
sign = numpy.sign(x)
```

With regard to your 2nd question, that's quite easy.

Simply use:

```
int(bool(x))
```

### Edit:

With some tinkering i found a solution for your first question, too:

```
negsign = int(int(num) >> 31)
possign = int(num > 0)

sign = negsign + possign
```

Note that i did not thoroughly test this for special cases like `-0`.

Comment: Thank you! Out of curiosity, is that function `numpy.sign` implemented with `if` statements?

Comment: Probably, but most likely in C and not in python. :-D

Comment: Aw shucks, that snippet from the net didn't work correctly, i'll try to come up with something myself.

Comment: @Rohan The last edit should cover it all.

Comment: Is that bitwise operators?

Comment: @Rohan Yes, `x >> y` shifts x to the right by `y` bits. `>` is just the garden variety "greater than" operator.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you so desperately want to avoid if statements? Embrace them!

```
def reducer(numbers):
    for n in numbers:
        if n > 0:
            n = 1
        elif n < 0:
            n = -1
```

Comment: Most likely because it is an assignment...

Answer (score 0):

Any non-zero number, say `x`, can be mapped to `-1`/`1` for negative/positive, respectively, as `x/|x|`.

```
arr = [-15, -0.6, 3, 0, 27, -16]
arrFixed = list(map(lambda x : 0 if x==0 else x/abs(x), arr))
print(arrFixed)
# [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0, 1.0, -1.0]
```

Comment: You're using `if` there :-)

Comment: @sobek Ow you're right, I missed that (somewhat strange, homework assignment?) demand in the question, thanks! I see now I also that OP added a second question (w.r.t. the one I initially misread x) ) that I haven't answered either. Anyway author got his answer with `.sign` (which most likely contains the same if check vs. 0 as I do above :) ).

Comment: You're absolutely right. :-) If you're interested, i dug up another solution that does it with integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use math.copysign(x,y).  However, it maps 0 to +1, so you need some more imagination, e.g.

```
for x in [-10,0,4]: 
    print(math.copysign(0.5,x)-math.copysign(0.5,-x))

-1.0
0.0
1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[(lambda x: x if x == 0 else x // abs(x))(x) for x in arr]
```

fixed: now it works also for negative numbers.

Comment: This doesn't change numbers less than 0 to -1.

Comment: @MorganThrapp right, I've missed that, fixed.